# Nmap port-unreachable for busybox binaries

Tags: udp, nmap, busybox

I need to scan the open ports from ubuntu pc to nxp based board. I used nmap for that purpose. In Board busybox provided micro clients like ntp & udhcpc. Actually NTP is working as expected for syncing with the server time. But while scanning from ubuntu pc it shows port-unreachable.

So I tried installing NTP from yocto image and removed ntp from busybox. Now nmap shows the port is open.

Is there any way to proceed further while using busybox clients? Since dhcpclient & NTP produced from yocto makes the size of the filesystem larger.